# how to print a list in below format

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

The following code is converting two dictionaries into a list:

```
payment_no=[]
for i in df2:
    payment_list=[]
    for k in df3:   
        if df2[i]['Payment_Number'] == df3[k]['Payment_Number']:
            payment_list.append(df3[k])
    payment_no.append('Payment_No:'+df2[i]['Payment_Number'])
    payment_no.append(payment_list)
print(payment_no)
```

When I run it, I get the below output:

```
['Payment_Number:197330238',
[{'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013156', 'Invoice Date': '5/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments',}, {'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013140', 'Invoice Date': '4/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments',}, {'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013182', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments', }],
'Payment_Number:197330238',
[{'Payment_Number': '197330295', 'Invoice Number': '61700018202-TDS-CM-7855', 'Invoice Date': '4/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan}, {'Payment_Number': '197330295', 'Invoice Number': '61700018247-TDS-CM-7302', 'Invoice Date': '5/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan, }, {'Payment_Number': '197330295', 'Invoice Number': '64100010621-TDS-CM-2516', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan}\].................................]
```

but i need the following output:

```
[{'Payment_Number': '197330238', Line:{'Invoice Number': '80600013156', 'Invoice Date': '5/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'}, { 'Invoice Number': '80600013140', 'Invoice Date': '4/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'}, { 'Invoice Number': '80600013182', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'},
{'Payment Number':'197330295' ,Line:[{'Invoice Number': '61700018202-TDS-CM-7855', 'Invoice Date': '4/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan}, { 'Invoice Number': '61700018247-TDS-CM-7302', 'Invoice Date': '5/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan}, { 'Invoice Number': '64100010621-TDS-CM-2516', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan},
............................................]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Like @anishtain said, I wish you would have provided more code/information about your situation. Regardless, I still tried to help you.

Based on the final result and your code, I came up with this for the sample data. Its not accurate by any means.

```py
df2 = {
    0 : {'Payment_Number': '197330238'} ,
    1 : {'Payment_Number': '197330238'} ,
    2 : {'Payment_Number': '197330238'} ,
    3: {'Payment_Number': '197330238'},
    4: {'Payment_Number': '197330295'},
    5: {'Payment_Number': '197330295'},
    6: {'Payment_Number': '197330295'}
}

nan = 0 # temp value;  may not be accurate

df3 = {
    0: {'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013182', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'},
    1: {'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013156', 'Invoice Date': '5/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'},
    2: {'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013140', 'Invoice Date': '4/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'},
    3: {'Payment_Number': '197330238', 'Invoice Number': '80600013182', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Invoice', 'Transaction Description': 'Payments'},
    4: {'Payment_Number': '197330295', 'Invoice Number': '61700018202-TDS-CM-7855', 'Invoice Date': '4/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan},
    5: {'Payment_Number': '197330295', 'Invoice Number': '61700018247-TDS-CM-7302', 'Invoice Date': '5/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan},
    6: {'Payment_Number': '197330295', 'Invoice Number': '64100010621-TDS-CM-2516', 'Invoice Date': '6/2/2022', 'Transaction type': 'Others', 'Transaction Description': nan}
}
```

Solution #1:

```py
payment_no = []
unique_no = set(df2[i]['Payment_Number'] for i in df2)  # takes all unique numbers from dicts in list
for num in unique_no:
   payment_list = []
   for k in df3:   
       if num == df3[k]['Payment_Number']:
           # prevents the "Payment_Number" key from being removed from df3 permanently
           payment_list.append({key:value for key,value in df3[k].items() if key != 'Payment_Number'}) 
   payment_no.append('Payment_No: '+ num)
   payment_no.append(payment_list)

# skips every two indexes because those are pairs
for i in range(0, len(payment_no), 2):
   print(payment_no[i], 'Lines:',payment_no[i+1])
```

[What the result would look like with added visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHp6H.png)

[What the result should look like in terminal without the color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9MYp.png)This is still somewhat messy but does not have redundant data.

Solution #2 - use a list of dictionaries

```py
payment_no = []
unique_no = set(df2[i]['Payment_Number'] for i in df2)  # takes all unique numbers from dicts in list
for num in unique_no:
    payment_list = []
    for k in df3:   
        if num == df3[k]['Payment_Number']:
            # prevents the "Payment_Number" key from being removed from df3 permanently
            payment_list.append({key:value for key,value in df3[k].items() if key != 'Payment_Number'}) 
    
    temp = {'Payment_No': num, 'Lines': payment_list}
    payment_no.append(temp)

for d in payment_no:
    print(d)
```

[What the result should look like in terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DsyH.png)

This is probably not the best solution, but I hope it helps.